# How can I use With and LeftJoin in the same Simple.Data Query?

Tags: c#, simple.data

I am using Simple.Data to try and build a query from our Database. Basically the results need to include certain columns from a Users table, as well as multiple rows from an Addresses table, as well as one specific column from an Entity Table.

```
Database.Users.FindAll(query)
              .With(Database.Users.Addresses.As("Address"))
              .LeftJoin(Database.Entities).On(Database.Users.ParentEntityId == Database.Entities.EntityID)
              .Select(Database.Users.UserID,
                     Database.Users.FirstName,
                     Database.Users.LastName,
                     Database.Entities.Name.As("ParentEntityName"));
```

The odd thing is if I don't have the `With` statement in my query this works fine (though I would be missing the Address), but with it I end up getting "The given key was not present in the dictionary".

Also should note that including the `With` and excluding the `Database.Entities.Name.As("ParentEntityName")` works as well, but I'm missing that value.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out LeftJoin and With don't play nice together when you specify what you want in the Select statement. I ended up getting around this issue using a WithOne statement with a LeftJoin to get the entire row from the table, then just got the value from there - not the most elegant fix but it works.

```
dynamic entity;
Database.Users.FindAll(query)
              .With(Database.Users.Addresses.As("Address"))
              .LeftJoin(Entities.As("Entity"), out entity).On(Users.ParentEntityId == entity.EntityID)
              .WithOne(entity)
              .Select(Database.Users.UserID,
                      Database.Users.FirstName,
                      Database.Users.LastName);
```

Then when I turned the results to a list I got the value from "Entity" in the SimpleQuery as a SimpleRecord, which contained `name` which was the value I wanted.